# Problems with plt.subplots, which should be the best option?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm new in both python and stackoverflow... I come from the ggplot2 R background and I am still getting stacked with python. I don't understand why I have a null plot before my figure using matplotlib... I just have a basic `pandas` series and I want to plot some of the rows in a subplot, and some on the others (however my display is terrible and I don't know why/how to fix it). Thank you in advance!

```
df = organism_df.T
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(5,5))
ax1 = df.iloc[[0,2,3,-1]].plot(kind='bar')
ax1.get_legend().remove()
ax1.set_title('Number of phages/bacteria interacting vs actual DB')

ax2 = df.iloc[[1,4,5,6,7]].plot(kind='bar')
ax2.get_legend().remove()
ax2.set_title('Number of different taxonomies with interactions')

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `plot` from `pandas` would need the axes given as an argument, e.g., `df.plot(ax=ax1, kind='bar')`. In your example, first the figure (consisting of ax1 and ax2) is created, *then*  another figure is created by the plot function (at the same time overwriting the original ax1 object) etc.